# JS event similar to render-partials-response in wordpress customiser selective refresh when the request is initialised?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm writing CSS generated by PHP in the head of the page. When a setting is changed, there is no feedback to the user while the request is in progress.

If it was part of the body, I could have used the .customize-partial-refreshing class added.

I'm looking for something similar to **render-partials-response**, that is triggered when the request for partial is initiated.

Link to the core file where this event can be added.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/js/customize-selective-refresh.js#L770

Comment: Please share the code you're working with.